# Is there any dataset to convert text to sign language?

Tags: natural-language-processing

I'm going to start working on one university project and I would like to ask a question regarding it. My project is about "Sign language synthesis from NLP" and I need to develop an application where:

1. Take spoken language from user microphone
2. Recognize a word with an algorithm and convert words to sign language

Output should be images with sign language.

For instance, if we say "I go home", we should have images of those words in sign language.

My question is that is there any dataset you would recommend to get the images for the sign language?